# How do I capture stderr from Fabric's local command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric, stderr

Fabric v1.4.3 does not capture the output of 'python --version'

```
def python_v():
    m = local('python --version', capture=True)
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`local` with `capture=True` returns the command's `stdout`; a simple test shows that `python --version` prints the version info on `stderr`. So, you can try to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` in the command:

```
m = local('python --version 2>&1', capture=True)
```

Comment: or use: ``print m.stderr`` without the redirect

Answer (score 10):

I find the following way cleaner than the accepted answer:

`print m.stderr`

(Thanks remosu!)