# How to show error encountered during Fabric local()

Tags: python, fabric

If Fabric encounters an error code when executing a `local()` command, it throws an exception like:

```
Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing '...'
```

However, it doesn't actually show any `stdout` or `stderr` from the command, even if you specify `capture=True`, which is immensely unhelpful. There are explanations on [how to capture these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153601/fabric-local-doesnt-capture), but because Fabric throws an exception, you can't save the result from `local()` and introspect it.

How do you get Fabric to show useful error messages during errors encountered when running `local()`?

Comment: Late... but I would advise possibly looking at gusset, a project a member of my company has worked on. https://github.com/locationlabs/gusset/blob/master/gusset/output.py

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance you still care it is possible to use a tool from github to accomplish this; [Gusset](https://github.com/locationlabs/gusset)

If you choose to follow this option your code would look like this:

```
from gusset.output import with_output
from fabric.api import local, task

@with_output(verbosity=2)
@task
def my_failing_task():
    local("blahblah")

In [4]: my_failing_task()
[localhost] local: blahblah
/bin/sh: 1: blahblah: not found

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'blahakh'

None

Aborting.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

Also I image you can just take the [code](https://github.com/locationlabs/gusset/blob/master/gusset/output.py) from Gusset, and just paste it into your own application